# Define static data in separate place to reuse

Tags: java, enums

I have list of string data that are not change during any operation inside my program. But i need to access those data in several places by using key.

As a example: (1,ANN)(2,ALEX)(3,ANDROW)

Is there any way to store these data in separate class.Can I use java enum for this. thank you

Comment: Perhaps, a static map ?

Comment: What is the problem with `HashMap`?

Answer (score 2):

With the use of **enum** you can implement something like below:

```
public enum Name {

ONE {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "ANN";
            }
        },
TWO {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "ALEX";
            }
        },
THREE {
            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "ANDROW";
            }
        };

public abstract String getName();

}
```

Then you can get the the names :

```
System.out.println(Name.ONE.getName());
```

Comment: IMHO, a better style would be to define a constructor for that enum - 

public Name(String name) {
 this.name=name; }; you can then simply define ONE("ANN"),TWO("ALEX")

Comment: If you implement like  that how do you going to get the out-put ?`System.out.println(Name.ONE);`??

Comment: you'll need to define a (static final field) in the enum class... I'll give a sample

Answer (score 1):

This is really a good candidate for using Map. Where you can use your numbers as keys and String's as values.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map<Integer,String>` is one option and if key is also constant you could define string variable like

```
public static final string ONE = "ANN";
public static final string TWO = "ALEX";
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way to use enums to define a statically mapping:

```
public enum Names {
ONE("ANN"),
TWO("ALEX"),
THREE("ANDREW");

private final String name;
private Names(String name){
  this.name=name;
}

public String getName() {
   return this.name;
}
}
```

This is only applicable to real-static values (change to values does mean a code change), but you can easily define multiple properties as well.

Comment: name is a default field in ENUM. `ONE.name()` returns "ONE" so use differnt variable nmae within enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    static HashMap<Integer,String>data = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        data.put(data.size(),"ALEX");   // if you want 1-based indexing,
        data.put(data.size(),"ANDROW"); // then use data.size()+1
        data.put(data.size(),"ANN");    // instead of data.size()

        for (int i = 0; i<data.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(i+" : "+data.get(i)); // use i+1 if 1-based indexing
        }

    }
}
```